# How to verify Package Signature when using Nuget.Packaging on .Net Framework

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, digital-signature

I am consuming Nuget.Packaging library from a component targeting .Net Framework 4.7.1. I notice that the methods that works on .Net 6/7 do not work the same way. I can see that I can open the signature file stream. Is there a way to use the Primary Signature and/or other way to validate the signature or get the signature content details. I need to validate the subject and issuer details to validate right source of the package.

```
var s = SignedPackageArchiveUtility.OpenPackageSignatureFileStream(new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("Signed.nupkg")));
```

// ...